# Why is my button not being rounded in RubyMotion?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I have a button in a RubyMotion app, created in the `viewDidLoad` method of my view controller class. It looks like this:

```
def viewDidLoad
    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)

    @button.setTitle("Tap!", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    @button.frame = [ [85, 250], [150, 50] ]
    @button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor
    @button.addTarget(self, action: :actionForTheButton, forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(@button)
end
```

However, my button looks like this:

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening with the button, since I thought that the `buttonWithType` method, containing the argument of `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` made a rectangular button with rounded corners. Can anyone clarify what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to stay away from `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` now that it's deprecated. 
SOURCE: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

You can round any UIView by setting the cornerRadius on the layer though.

I recommend rounding your UIView layer like so:

```
def viewDidLoad
    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeSystem)

    @button.setTitle("Tap!", forState: UIControlStateNormal)
    @button.frame = [ [85, 250], [150, 50] ]
    @button.layer.cornerRadius = 10 # SET THE ROUNDING RADIUS HERE
    @button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor
    @button.addTarget(self, action: :actionForTheButton, forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(@button)
end
```